# Does the spock test code not prevent the mistake of putting the generated instance as a parameter?

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, spock

I am testing using the spock framework in groovy language.
I want to test TestService, and TestService uses TestRepository as below code.

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class TestService {

    private final TestRepository repository;
```

The test code I intended is to create the TestRepository as a mock object and put it in as a parameter, as shown below.

```
class SpockTest extends Specification {

    private TestRepository repository = Mock()

    private TestService target = new TestService(repository)
```

However, Spock cannot be checked during compile time even if the TestService is created and put as a parameter as shown in the code below.

```
class SpockTest extends Specification {

    private TestRepository repository = Mock()

    private TestService target = new TestService(target) // It doesn't prevent mistakes.
```

What I'm curious about is how Spock works, so is this possible?
Or, I wonder if there is another way to prevent this mistake.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This question is completely incomprehensible to me. I have no idea what you are trying to achieve, and I do not like guessing. Please learn [how to ask a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thank you.

Comment: Thank you.
But what part of it doesn't make sense?
I simply wonder why the code below works. Is it because of the dynamic language characteristics of groovy?


private TestService target = new TestService(target)

Comment: Luckily, Leonard understood your question and now I do, too, after reading his answer and then your question again. For me, the wording was unclear. That you only provided incomplete snippets instead of full classes, did not help either - hence my educational links with advice to write better questions. This recommendation still stands. As for your question as such, Leonard already answered it. Groovy != Java, and a dynamic language does not stop you from making some silly mistakes right at compile time like Java does. But the bug is easy enough to spot when you run the test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean it doesn't prevent mistakes? If you actually run any tests it will fail with a `NullPointerException`.

What you are experiencing here is one of the drawbacks of a dynamic language, you are basically passing in `null` as the `target` property is not initialized yet. You could try adding `@CompileStatic` or `@TypeChecked`, but they don't work 100% with Spock, and it is generally not advisable to do so.

You should add `@NonNull` to your code to prevent `null` being passed in, doing do will [generate](https://projectlombok.org/features/constructor) an explicit null check.

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class TestService {

    @NonNull
    private final TestRepository repository;
```

Comment: Of course, I can check NullPointerException by writing and executing a test code using TestRepository.
However, does the code below work because of the characteristics of Groovy's dynamic language?


private TestService target = new TestService(target)

Comment: Well, work is relative, but yeah it will compile and execute and then will fail the test.

Answer (score 0):

> *However, Spock cannot be checked **during compile time** even if the TestService is created and put as a parameter as shown in the code below.*

Groovy is a dynamic language so there's no compile time for your test class but runtime only. Although it's possible to force static compilation for Groovy language, it will break your test because Spock heavily relies on the flexibility and dynamic nature of Groovy. That's why you cannot protect yourself from such errors using a compiler.

Personally, I would not recommend using Groovy and Spock for testing. I prefer to have full compiler support while developing tests. From my experience, writing unit tests in Groovy (with dynamic compilation at runtime) looks tempting at the beginning because the test code is maybe less verbose and using Spock is more readable but eventually, it will become hell when your system evolves. When you modify your code under tests and have many tests to refactor it will cost you much more effort to correct all the runtime errors caused by the modified code. You will have to perform many run-test-refactor iterations to fix all of them in comparison to using a statically compiled language. If I were you I would use statically compiled Groovy + JUnit5 and get rid of Spock exactly because of the reason.

Comment: I disagree with your personal opinion. Over the last 12 or so years, as an agile coach I have introduced Spock and Geb to many development teams, and none ever looked back or wanted their JUnit 4/5 + Mockito/PowerMock back. Spock tests are pretty easy to maintain and debug. In my agile teams, both application code and tests get refactored all the time, and using Spock has saved much more time than the occasional, rare case in which debugging in Java would have been easier than in Groovy, has cost. I would choose Spock over JUnit anytime. Like each tool, you simply need to learn how to use it.